# Ubuntu Emulator doesn't proceed after entering the passphrase

Tags: ubuntu-emulator

I have configured Ubuntu Emulator in Ubuntu 16.04. I went through initial security settings and user familiarization steps. After initial steps I restarted the emulator and it ask for a pass-phrase. After I goggling I entered 0000 as the pass-phrase but it still keep asking for a pass-phrase. What should I do to proceed ?

At the same time I can see a error statement in the log

`Failed to start RenderThread`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `--password` flag which can be used to override the default password.

Comment: Please mention with which command should I use --password parameter. run command has no a --password parameter

Comment: As you mentioned I used --password parameter when creating the instance with create command but still the issue exists.